# A non-principal ultra filter containing the even numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

I just started trying to read through Lectures on the Hyperreals: An Introduction to Nonstandard Analysis, by Robert Goldblatt. I'm near the beginning in the section on filters.  One of the exercises asks to prove that there exists a non-principal ultra filter on $\Bbb N$ containing the set of even numbers.

It seems to me that if I take the set of even numbers and all of its supersets, that should do it.  The smallest intersection will always contain the set of even numbers, so it can't be a singleton.  The complement of the set of even numbers is not in the filter.  The complement of any superset of the evens, will not contain the set of evens and is thus not in the filter.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The collection of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ that contain all the even numbers is a filter but it's not an **ultra** filter: the set of all numbers divisible by $4$ is not in your filter, and neither is its complement.